# How to insert missing numbers that depends on multiple columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I have this kind of table:

[image: img]

What you can see is that I have a missing month number which is 1. 
What I want is to insert a value that is like this to my table:

```
Month  Year  Col1        Forecast   Customer
1      2015  HD/FB/BK/      0          AFC
```

since that was a missing month, so I want the forecast to be 0 value.

And my parameters for such insert would be by year,col1 and customer.

Comment: I dont get your missing number .. there is month 1 after 12 , what do you mean by missing number ?

Comment: as I said, the missing month depends on per row and by year, col1, and customer's value. So you can see there that I want to insert the missing month which is 1 and that is according to the year 2015, col1: HD/FB/BK/ and by customer: AFC

Answer (score 1):

First, generate rows of all month-year combination based on your parameters. Then use `NOT EXISTS` to insert missing rows:

```
DECLARE @yr         INT,
        @col1       VARCHAR(50),
        @customer   VARCHAR(50);

WITH Cte(mnt, yr, col1, customer) AS(
    SELECT *, @yr, @col1, @customer
    FROM(VALUES
        (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
    )t(N)
)
INSERT INTO tbl(Month, Year, Col1, Forecast, Customer)
    SELECT
        mnt,
        yr,
        col1,
        0,
        customer
    FROM Cte c
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM tbl
            WHERE
                Col1 = c.col1
                AND Customer = c.customer
                AND Month = c.mnt
                AND Year = c.yr
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach here is to generate combinations of `month` and `col1` and match with the current table and generate the insert for missing rows. You may extend this with other required combinations of `customer` and `year`. This works well if there is no single entry for a particular combination.

### Step 1: Create combinations table

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 1 month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months
        JOIN
    (SELECT 'HD/FB/BK' colname UNION ALL SELECT 'HD/FB/BL') col1
```

### Step 2: Find missing items

```
select expected.* from data_table dt right join (SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 1 month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months
        JOIN
    (SELECT 'HD/FB/BK' colname UNION ALL SELECT 'HD/FB/BL') col1) expected on (dt.month = expected.month and dt.Col1 = expected.colname) where dt.col1 is null
```

### Step 3: Insert missing values (All combined)

```
insert into data_table
select datainsert.month, 2015, datainsert.colname, 0.0, 'AFC' FROM
(select expected.* from data_table dt right join (SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 1 month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months
        JOIN
    (SELECT 'HD/FB/BK' colname UNION ALL SELECT 'HD/FB/BL') col1) expected on (dt.month = expected.month and dt.Col1 = expected.colname) where dt.col1 is null) datainsert;
```